# maven shade plugin bringind old dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I am using Maven-Shade-Plugin. This is my app structure

```
app
 -> Core
 -> ModuleA
```

I want to have Core as dependency in ModuleA. Core declared bunch of dependencies, few being Flyway and Postgressql.

I assumed since Core is added as dependency in ModuleA, both flyway and Postgres will be included as well. I am building fat jar of ModuleA using Maven-Shade-Plugin.

But the problem is when I view the dependency tree of ModuleA, I see old versions of Flyway and Postgres getting included. I searched my entire classparth and the old versions are not there anywhere. I am not understanding how these old versions are coming. Am I doing something wrong with maven-shade-plugin?

Core pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

ModuleA pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>example</groupId>
                <artifactId>core</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
<executions>

                    <execution>
                        <id>shade-my-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
<artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-common</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>

                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            </transformers>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

When I check the build output, I see

```
[INFO] Including org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:3.2.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4.1212.jre7 in the shaded jar.
```

I am not able to figure out how/where it is getting 3.2.1 for flyway and 9.4.1212 for Postgres when the versions declared in core are different.

Comment: You can use mvn dependency:tree to view dependencies. Also, in Core you can add dependencyManagement section, where you can write required versions of used dependencies

Comment: I did check through mvn dependency:tree and thats how I saw that older versions of dependencies is coming in ModuleA. How will dependencyManagement section help? I listed the dependency and its version in the dependencies section right?